# Converting ErrorType to NSError loses associated objects

Tags: swift, error-handling, swift2

In Swift 2.0 `NSError` conforms to the `ErrorType` protocol.

For a customly defined error, we can specify the associating object(s) for some cases, like below.

```
enum LifeError: ErrorType {
    case BeBorn
    case LostJob(job: String)
    case GetCaughtByWife(wife: String)
    ...
}
```

We can comfortably do the following:

```
do {
    try haveAffairWith(otherPerson)
} catch LifeError.GetCaughtByWife(let wife) {
    ...
}
```

However if we want it to pass into other places as an `NSError`, it loses its associating object information.

```
println("\(LifeError.GetCaughtByWife("Name") as NSError)")
```

prints:

```
Error Domain=... Code=1 "The operation couldn't be completed". (... error 1)
```

and its `userInfo` is `nil`.

Where is my `wife` associated with the `ErrorType`?

Comment: Must feel for your Life optimism ❤️ Could it be that your wire is nil because you're not functional or maybe cuz you are confirming to Polyamory protocol and she's not?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**New in Xcode 8**: `CustomNSError` [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/customnserror).

```
enum LifeError: CustomNSError {
    case beBorn
    case lostJob(job: String)
    case getCaughtByWife(wife: String)

    static var errorDomain: String {
        return "LifeError"
    }

    var errorCode: Int {
        switch self {
        case .beBorn:
            return 0
        case .lostJob(_):
            return 1
        case .getCaughtByWife(_):
            return 2
        }
    }

    var errorUserInfo: [String : AnyObject] {
        switch self {
        case .beBorn:
            return [:]
        case .lostJob(let job):
            return ["Job": job]
        case .getCaughtByWife(let wife):
            return ["Wife": wife]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: we don't need LifeError to conform to the Error protocol. CustomNSError inherits from Error.

Answer (score 24):

An `ErrorType` can't really be casted to an `NSError`, you have to take the associated data and package it into an `NSError` yourself.

```
do {
    try haveAffairWith(otherPerson)
} catch LifeError.GetCaughtByWife(let wife) {
    throw NSError(domain:LifeErrorDomain code:-1 userInfo:
        [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:"You cheated on \(wife)")
}
```

EDIT: Actually you can do the cast from `ErrorType` to `NSError`, but the `NSError` you get from the default implementation is quite primitive.  What I'm doing in my app is hooking application:willPresentError: in my app delegate and using a custom class to read the my app's `ErrorType`'s and decorate NSErrors to return.

Comment: That's what I've learned. When casting it directly to `NSError`, it will only translate the error code and the error domain. I think I have to assemble `NSError` for myself. Thanks!

Comment: I fiddled with this for an hour today, the fact that you can't throw the associated data over the fence is... frustrating.

Comment: did someone of you already file a radar for this ? I have the same issue und would like to dup it!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a defect or a feature request, and I'm not sure exactly how it should work.  There are two related problems: (1) the platform seems to silently convert `ErrorType` to `NSError`, and (2) if you had an special enum `ErrorType` you were using, there's no way to hook NSApp.presentError() to present it in an appropriate way.

Comment: Casting preserves more than just `code` and `domain`, for example it does preserve `localizedFailureReason`. See the bottom of [this Playground](https://github.com/nezhyborets/ios-case-study-playgrounds/blob/master/ErrorToNSError.playground/Contents.swift) for details.

Comment: @OleksiiNezhyborets That's true in Swift 3, they've rejiggered the `ErrorType` along with renaming it to `Error`.

Answer (score 14):

Creating an `NSError` in every catch block can lead to a lot of copy and paste to convert your custom `ErrorType` to `NSError`. I abstracted it away similar to [@powertoold](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32936465/1329214).

```
protocol CustomErrorConvertible {
    func userInfo() -> Dictionary<String,String>?
    func errorDomain() -> String
    func errorCode() -> Int
}
```

This extension can hold code, that's common for the `LifeError` we already have and other custom error types we may create.

```
extension CustomErrorConvertible {
    func error() -> NSError {
        return NSError(domain: self.errorDomain(), code: self.errorCode(), userInfo: self.userInfo())
    }
}
```

Off to the implementation!

```
enum LifeError: ErrorType, CustomErrorConvertible {
    case BeBorn
    case LostJob(job: String)
    case GetCaughtByPolice(police: String)

    func errorDomain() -> String {
        return "LifeErrorDomain"
    }

    func userInfo() -> Dictionary<String,String>? {
        var userInfo:Dictionary<String,String>?
        if let errorString = errorDescription() {
            userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: errorString]
        }
        return userInfo
    }

    func errorDescription() -> String? {
        var errorString:String?
        switch self {
        case .LostJob(let job):
            errorString = "fired as " + job
        case .GetCaughtByPolice(let cops):
            errorString = "arrested by " + cops
        default:
            break;
        }
        return errorString
    }

    func errorCode() -> Int {
        switch self {
        case .BeBorn:
            return 1
        case .LostJob(_):
            return -9000
        case .GetCaughtByPolice(_):
            return 50
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how to use it.

```
func lifeErrorThrow() throws {
    throw LifeError.LostJob(job: "L33tHax0r")
}

do {
    try lifeErrorThrow()
}
catch LifeError.BeBorn {
  print("vala morgulis")
}
catch let myerr as LifeError {
    let error = myerr.error()
    print(error)
}
```

You could easily move certain functions like `func userInfo() -> Dictionary<String,String>?` from `LifeError` to `extension CustomErrorConvertible` or a different extension.

Instead of hardcoding the error codes like above an enum might be preferable.

```
enum LifeError:Int {
  case Born
  case LostJob
}
```

Comment: I believe if you have `LifeError` adopt `CustomNSError`, you can use `LifeError` as an `NSError` in catch closure. Meaning
`myerro.errorCode`

Answer (score 6):

My solution to this problem was to create an enum that conforms to Int, ErrorType:

```
enum AppError: Int, ErrorType {
    case UserNotLoggedIn
    case InternetUnavailable
}
```

And then extend the enum to conform to CustomStringConvertible and a custom protocol called CustomErrorConvertible:

```
extension AppError: CustomStringConvertible, CustomErrorConvertible

protocol CustomErrorConvertible {
    var error: NSError { get }
}
```

For the description and error, I switched on the AppError. Example:

```
Description:    switch self {
            case .UserNotLoggedIn: return NSLocalizedString("ErrorUserNotLoggedIn", comment: "User not logged into cloud account.")
            case .InternetUnavailable: return NSLocalizedString("ErrorInternetUnavailable", comment: "Internet connection not available.")
            }

Error:    switch self {
            case .UserNotLoggedIn: errorCode = UserNotLoggedIn.rawValue; errorDescription = UserNotLoggedIn.description
            case .InternetUnavailable: errorCode = InternetUnavailable.rawValue; errorDescription = InternetUnavailable.description
            }
```

And then I composed my own NSError:

```
return NSError(domain:NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!, code:errorCode, userInfo:[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: errorDescription])
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround in `PromiseKit` that may be a bit ugly but seems to work.

I paste here my playground so you can see the whole process.

```
import Foundation
import PromiseKit
import XCPlayground

let error = NSError(domain: "a", code: 1, userInfo: ["hello":"hello"])

// Only casting won't lose the user info

let castedError = error as ErrorType
let stillHaveUserInfo = castedError as NSError

// when using promises

func convert(error: ErrorType) -> Promise<Int> {
    return Promise<Int> {
        (fulfill, reject) in
        reject(error)
    }
}

let promiseA = convert(error)

// Seems to lose the user info once we cast back to NSError

promiseA.report { (promiseError) -> Void in
    let lostUserInfo = promiseError as NSError
}


// Workaround

protocol CastingNSErrorHelper {
    var userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] { get }
}

extension NSError : CastingNSErrorHelper {}

promiseA.report { (promiseError) -> Void in
    let castingNSErrorHelper = promiseError as! CastingNSErrorHelper
    let recoveredErrorWithUserInfo = castingNSErrorHelper as! NSError
}

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution that I found, is to have an Objective-C wrapper for casting the `ErrorType` to `NSError` (via `NSObject*` parmeter) and extracting the `userInfo`. Most likely this would work for other associated objects too.

In my case all other attempts using only Swift resulted in getting a `nil` `userInfo`.

Here is the Objective-C helper. Place it for example in a `MyErrorUtils` class exposed to Swift:

```
+ (NSDictionary*)getUserInfo:(NSObject *)error {
    NSError *nsError = (NSError *)error;
    if (nsError != nil) {
        return [nsError userInfo];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Then use the helper in Swift like this:

```
static func myErrorHandler(error: ErrorType) {

    // Note the as? cast to NSObject
    if let userInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject]? = 
        MyErrorUtils.getUserInfo(error as? NSObject) {

        let myUserInfo = userInfo["myCustomUserInfo"]

        // ... Error processing based on userInfo ...
    }

}
```

(I'm currently using XCode 8 and Swift 2.3)

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer pointed out, there's now `CustomNSError` in Swift 3, however, you don't necessarily need to use it. If you define your error type like this

```
@objc
enum MyErrorType: Int, Error { ... }
```

Then this error can directly be casted to `NSError`:

```
let error: MyErrorType = ...
let objcError = error as NSError
```

I just discovered that today and though I share it with the world.

Comment: Any kind of error can be casted to `NSError`, not only `Int` and/or `@objc` ones.

Comment: @Cristik But if the error type is not `Int`, you will not have constant error code numbers and thus you cannot catch theses error in Obj-C code in a meaningful way if the error is thrown by a library you link to as binary compatibility is only guaranteed with constant error code numbers. Obj-C requires error code numbers to be known in advance at compile time and to stay equal across binary releases. Swift has no such requirement as it catches error dynamically.

Comment: Yeah, but error codes are not enough to uniquely identify errors, the error domain is also needed, and this is generated based on the Swift type name.

Comment: @Cristik That's not the point. The point is, if you want to handle that error in Obj-C, you better make sure that each error code has a fixed Int value and this can only be done in two ways: You make errors of type `Int` or you implement `CustomNSError`. If you do neither, you can still cast the Swift error to `NSError` but you cannot handle that error in Obj-C code in a way that is save across binary releases.